# How to increase WooCommerce product variation price based on month

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I have a product created in WooCommerce that has two variations with different prices: Seasonal and Annual. Is there a way to increase *only* the Yearly variation’s price based on month? E.g. From Jan to May, the Yearly price is $100, but from June to Dec the price is +50% (so $150 in this example). The Seasonal variation price remains the same throughout the year. My initial thought was to use the Sale Price field and schedule, but this adds sale badges and price strikethroughs which I don’t want since this technically isn’t a product sale price.

I’ve installed several plugins that fall short of this particular requirement. The [WooCommerce Dynamic Pricing](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-dynamic-pricing/) plugin also doesn’t appear to support specific price variation increases either.

I also considered duplicating these products (there are only 8) and installing a scheduling plugin to show/hide the appropriate products, but since the scheduling date includes the year this would require a user updating the date setting every year, which isn’t often I know, but I’d like it not to require any user interaction at all.

Ideally, there’s a plugin available to accomplish this, but I’m also semi-comfortable writing custom code given direction to the appropriate hooks.

Thanks in advance for any help/advice!

Answer (score 0):

Concerning 'but this adds sale badges and price strikethroughs which I don’t want since this technically isn’t a product sale price':

The filter 'woocommerce_format_sale_price' will allow you to change how the sale price is displayed. E.g., you can change:

```
<del><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
    <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&#36;</span>2.00</span>
</del>
<ins><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
    <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&#36;</span>1.77</span>
</ins>
```

to:

```
<ins><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
    <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&#36;</span>1.77</span>
</ins>
```

The `<del>` element contains the strikethrough.

However, this doesn't solve your scheduling problem.